# Normal Lines on graph of sideways Parabola

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The graph shows the normal lines from the point $(2,0)$ to the graph of the parabola $x = y^2$. How many normal lines are there from the point $(x_0, 0)$ to the graph of the parabola in the following cases?
$$
\begin{align}
x_0 &= 1/7 \\
x_0 &= 1/2 \\
x_0 &= 1
\end{align}
$$
At what value of $x_0$ will the normal lines be perpendicular?

I'm really lost on this and have been working on it for over 2-3 hours. I can't seem to get the concept. I'm not looking for answers(although greatly appreciated) If someone could provide a clear and easy to understand explanation of the concept to solve this it would be great. I have thought about taking the derivative and setting it equal to the slope in order to find x_0 but I haven't really gotten anywhere. Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $x_0$. For each point $x$, there are, associated to $x$

- Points (either 0,1, or 2) on the graph of $x=y^2$
- Slopes between the points $(x, \pm\sqrt{x})$ and $(x_0 ,0)$, and
- Slopes of the graph, $f'(x)$ (finite everywhere but at zero).

Write these down, and find out when #2 is perpendicular to #3. Do you know how to express the condition that two lines are perpendicular?

Comment: It seems that the OP is working with the parabola $x = y^2$, so we need to consider points of the form $(y^2, y)$ on the graph.

Comment: @SammyBlack Quite right. I edited my answer. Thanks